# Android Variables in Background

Tags: java, android, variables

I'd like to know how I can set a variable that will stay the same after I have closed the app. In this case I don't want to make it with a SharedPreference or a DataBase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious, why you don't want to use SharedPreferences or a database?  The only other option would be writing the variable values out to a file  and then reading it again when the app was re-opened.

Comment: This variable would be used to save if an "Time Booster" is active or not and another App with such a Time Booster is not using Shared Preference.. at least I couldn't find such a folder in the system files. Well, as it seems to be the best way, I'll go with the Shared Preferences. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

If the app gets closed any variable will be long gone on the next start.

The only way to keep data is to use persistence of some sort, and the most commonly used one is `SharedPreferences`.

You can alternatively write to a file, send your data to a server (and load it again on the next start), or use a database.

---

You can also make use of a `Service` which you keep running in the background, that keeps your values. But you will have no guarantee about when / how the system might stop it, and they would be lost—again—like before.

---

If you want to keep some value, you need to persist it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) But how could I persist it?

Answer (score 2):

Variables endure for the life cycle of an app. When user closes an app and that app is not running a service in the background everything is deleted. In some occurences(but this has a slight chance) static variables from previous session can be read incidentally if app is restarted again, but this is not a correct behaviour.

There are 3 ways to keep your data.

1. Write to file: You can create files in txt, json or in any other format you wish, and read from these files on runtime to get values from previous session. I don't prefer writing to file to keep data very much. If you don't know how to use database and want mess with it, you can use this.
2. Shared Preferences: This is generally for saving settings file with name and value pairs.
3. Writing to a database: You write your data to database. SQLite and Realm databases are the most popular ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) In case the option with the "persist" David Medenjak suggested won't work, I'll do it with the shared Preferences :)